# Google Script for Google Forms - send auto reminder to non-responders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, automation, google-forms

I want to use a Google Script to generate an automated reminder email to non-responders of a form.

My first question is this: Is it possible to use a google script to grab the "waiting for responses" email address list?

If this is possible, please see below in the code where I have noted "THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP"

Thanks in advance.

```
FORM_OPEN_DATE   =  "2017-05-18 08:00";
FORM_CLOSE_DATE  =  "2017-05-19 15:00";
EMAIL_REMINDER   =  "2017-05-18 17:00";

/* Initialize the form, setup time based triggers */
function Initialize() {

  deleteTriggers_();

  if ((FORM_OPEN_DATE !== "") && 
      ((new Date()).getTime() < parseDate_(FORM_OPEN_DATE).getTime())) { 
    closeForm();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm")
    .timeBased()
    .at(parseDate_(FORM_OPEN_DATE))
    .create();
  }

  if (FORM_CLOSE_DATE !== "") { 
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm")
    .timeBased()
    .at(parseDate_(FORM_CLOSE_DATE))
    .create(); 
  }

}

/* ==============================*/

/* THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

function autoGenEmail {
  var currentTime = d.toLocalTimeString;
  //Should both currentTime and EMAIL_REMINDER be strings? How can I make
  //the < comparison between the two values?
  if (currentTime < EMAIL_REMINDER) {
  // Get email addresses of nonresponders
  // Generate and send an email to nonresponders
}

*/

/* ==============================*/

/* Delete all existing Script Triggers */
function deleteTriggers_() {  
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();  
  for (var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}

/* Send a mail to the form owner when the form status changes */
function informUser_(subject) {
  var formURL = FormApp.getActiveForm().getPublishedUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), subject, formURL);  
}

/* Allow Google Form to Accept Responses */
function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
  informUser_("Your Google Form is now accepting responses");
}

/* Close the Google Form, Stop Accepting Reponses */
function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  deleteTriggers_();
  informUser_("Your Google Form is no longer accepting responses");
}

/* Parse the Date for creating Time-Based Triggers */
function parseDate_(d) {
  return new Date(d.substr(0,4), d.substr(5,2)-1, 
                  d.substr(8,2), d.substr(11,2), d.substr(14,2));
}
```